# No puedo enlazar UIButton con IBOutlet o no funcionan las IBActins, Object Exit por defecto !!

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Al intentar insertar un UIButton en un ViewController la ventana de propiedades del objeto me sale en el atributo Connection por defecto "Action" y en Object "Exit"

Me crea la función pero no crea la conexsion, ademas no puedo insertar un IBOutlet del Boton !!

Adjunto imagen !!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas el código del Action no me lo enlaza con la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te crea la conexión porque el punto en el código no esta marcado? eso pasa muchas veces con Xcode. Si pones el raton encima del circulito en el código debería marcarse en el xib el boton

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, tuve un lapsus y no me di cuenta que estaba intentando crear la conexión del UIButton en otro UIViewcontroller diferente donde estaba relacionado. Después de esto, me surge la pregunta ¿ Es posible crear una conexión de un Action del UIButton en otro UIViewController ?

Comment: Si varios controladores utilizan el mismo xib si se que puede

Comment: Ok, gracias. Esta es una valiosa información !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola me parece que eso es porque estas intentando ponerlo en otro controlador eso me ha salido a mi cuando quiero agregar una accion a un boton en otro controller que no es de el

Comment: Correcto así es !